# I need to loop simple delayed animations in jquery

Tags: jquery, loops, infinite-loop

Hi I have a set of images that fade in at different speed once that I need to loop infinitely.
Can someone help me with the code. It's really basic animation, but code that I found loops everything at the same speed. Can anyone help me place this animation into a loop that does the same fading in effect but loops infinitely. Thank you

---

Thank you for your help.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function anim() {
// fade in initial
$('#img-1').delay(0).fadeIn(500);;
$('#img-2').delay(0).fadeIn(500);
$('#txt-1').delay(0).fadeIn(500)
$('#txt-2').delay(0).fadeIn(500);
// move to set 2
$('#txt-1').delay(2000).fadeOut(500);
$('#txt-2').delay(2000).fadeOut(500);
$('#txt-3').delay(2000).fadeIn(500);
$('#txt-4').delay(2000).fadeIn(500);
$('#img-1').delay(5000).fadeOut(500);
$('#img-2').delay(5000).fadeOut(500);
$('#img-3').delay(5000).fadeIn(500);
$('#img-4').delay(5000).fadeIn(500);
// move to set 3
$('#txt-3').delay(8000).fadeOut(500);
$('#txt-4').delay(8000).fadeOut(500);
$('#txt-5').delay(8000).fadeIn(500);
$('#txt-6').delay(8000).fadeIn(500);
$('#img-3').delay(11000).fadeOut(500);
$('#img-4').delay(11000).fadeOut(500);
$('#img-5').delay(11000).fadeIn(500);
$('#img-6').delay(11000).fadeIn(500);
// move to set 4
$('#txt-5').delay(14000).fadeOut(500);
$('#txt-6').delay(14000).fadeOut(500);
$('#txt-7').delay(14000).fadeIn(500);
$('#txt-8').delay(14000).fadeIn(500);
$('#img-5').delay(17000).fadeOut(500);
$('#img-6').delay(17000).fadeOut(500);
$('#img-7').delay(17000).fadeIn(500);
$('#img-8').delay(17000).fadeIn(500);
});
</script>

<body>

<div id="home-right">
```

images

```
</body>
```

Comment: Use setInterval to call a function that loads the next image, keep track of the current image using a variable

Answer (score 1):

A little recursion with setTimeout should work.

```
$.fn.loopFadeAnimation = function (delay, fadeType, duration) {
    var that = $(this);

    delay = delay || 0;
    duration = duration || 0;

    // call animation
    $(this).delay(delay)[fadeType](duration);

    // call loopFadeAnimation again with a setTimeout
    setTimeout(function () {
        var newFadeType = ('fadeIn' === fadeType)
            ? 'fadeOut'
            : 'fadeIn';
        $(that).loopFadeAnimation(delay, newFadeType, duration);
    }, delay + duration);

    return $(this); // for chaining
};

$('#img-1').loopFadeAnimation(0, 'fadeIn', 500); // etc.
```

Comment: I actually have different delays and I'm trying to fade in elements at different speeds.

Comment: @user2088105 - So you would fadeOut #img-1 at a different speed than you would fade it in?

Comment: I actually have different delays and I'm trying to fade in elements at different speeds, it's this animation, I just need to loop it forever. http://www.glenpointeoffice.com/). sorry kind of new to jquery.

Comment: Is there a way to convert the entire animation and just run it variable infinitely or is there a simple code snippet that just says run animation again when it's done?

Comment: You could just wrap it all in a function, and then add up all your delays and fade durations, and then outside the function use a setInterval call to the function using that sum as the 2nd argument